# Where does eclipse store its default key bindings?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, key-bindings

I want to know command ids of all the default keybindings in eclipse. Is there a snappy way to get it?

I have searched all relevant eclipse folders for keywords like "ALT" "CTRL". But none of them have all the default operations.

For example : I have exported all the key preferences in a csv file that looks something like this:

> text editing | delete line | ctrl+d  | editing text |
>
> window       | next editor | ctrl+f6 | in windows   |

Now I need to know the corresponding command ids for all such keybindings. I want this to use in my vrapperrc file.

Answer (score 0):

The defaults come from all the plugins that contribute to the key binding service using the `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` extension point. The bindings are defined in the plugin.xml for each plugin.

So, for example, the `org.eclipse.ui` plugin defines bindings like:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
  <key
        commandId="org.eclipse.ui.newWizard"
        sequence="M1+N"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration" />
  <key
        commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.close"
        sequence="M1+W"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration" />
  ... many more ....
```

In a plugin you can all these bindings using the `getBindings` method of the `IBindingService` service:

```java
IBindingService bindingService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getAdapter(IBindingService.class);

Binding [] bindings = bindingService.getBindings();
```

`Binding` has a `getParameterizedCommand` method to get the command the key is bound to.

Comment: I found all plugin files in my home directory where I had installed eclipse. I searched for the 'org.eclipse.ui.bindings' in them. There were a few occurrences but they did not include all the commands that I see in the key preferences window of eclipse

Comment: The plugin.xml files are packaged up in the various Eclipse jar files in the Eclipse installation, you won't see them if you seach for files. You are going to have to write an Eclipse plugin to do this.

Comment: Is there any way for someone not writing an eclipse plugin?